# Rolling a die with an upper bound for one number result

Tags: probability

Rolling a die n times, and the exercise stops when a certain number (say, 5) has been rolled a specific number of times (say, 10).  Is the probability for rolling 10 x 5's out of the total number of rolls still approaching 16.7%? or is placing an upper bound for that specific outcome changing the probability?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the simpler case of stopping at the first 5.
The probability that the first five will occur with the $n$th roll is $(\frac 56)^{n-1}\cdot \frac16$. Hence the expected proportion of fives ($1$) among the rolls ($n$) is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac 56\right)^{n-1}\cdot \frac16}n $$
and even without computing the limit, oce quickly sees that this is $>\frac16$ (the first summand).

Comment: Many thanks.  So how would you formulate the expression of the proportion so that it is expressed as the pth instance of that number occurring?  Sorry for the question, but it has been decades since my university days, and I am struggling.

Comment: You may find it helpful to use the fact that the probability of having the $r$-th $5$ occur on the $n$-th roll is $$\color{blue}{\binom{n-1}{n-r}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-r}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^r},$$ for $n\ge r$. Search online for **negative binomial distribution** for more info.

Comment: Again many thanks.  I think this is the answer I was looking for.